# Проблема с многопоточностью

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, многопоточность

Доброго времени суток! У меня такой вопрос. есть сайт asp.net mvc 
У него есть вот такой action со следующим кодом:

```
public ActionResult GetObjects(string search, int? objectType)
{
    var fact = new SqlServerProvider();         
    var db = fact.Create("some", conn, "~/MyFile.xml") as IDataSource; //проблемная строка  

    var req = ParseRequest(db, search, objectType);
    IObjectsSet set = db.GetObjects(req);
    var items = new List<DataItem>();

    // заполнение items

    return PartialView(new ObjectsViewModel(items, search));

}
```

К этому экшену приходят почти одновременно два запроса с разными параметрами search которые влияют на возвращаемый html код. И примерно в 4 случаях из пяти он возвращает одинаковую разметку (это неправильное поведение) а в пятом случае - разную разметку (правильное поведение). Так как запросы приходят почти одновременно я прихожу к выводу что дело скорее всего в многопоточности. Ок, я делаю лок и модифицирую пролблемный код экшна, помеченный комментарием, вот так (код, который нужно лочить я нашел тупым перебором. Сначала залочил весь экшн а потом постепенно сужал область лока):

```
IDataSource db; 
lock(ObjectsLocker) 
{
    db = fact.Create("some", conn, "~/MyFile.xml") as IDataSource;   // проблема исчезла
}
```

Этот лок действительно помогает и проблема исчезает. Теперь каждый раз экшн отрабатывает верно.

Но у меня остается вопрос, почему вообще возникала эта проблема? Внутри экшена используются только локальные переменные область жизни которых находится внутри этого экшна. Статических переменных или переменных класса я тут не использовал, поэтому потокам вроде бы не за что конкурировать. Почему же тогда возникала эта проблема, которую решил лок?

Сначала у меня были подозрения на метод `factory.Create` но он вроде тоже чистый. Вот его код:

```
public IBaseProvider Create(string sourceName, string connectionString, string objectDataSchemeFile)
{
    var db = new ObjectsDatabase(sourceName, connectionString, objectDataSchemeFile);   
    return db;
}
```

Comment: что за переменная conn?

Comment: Что такое `ObjectsDatabase`? Если это ваш класс - приведите его код. Очевидно же, что ошибка именно там.

Comment: @Grundy  conn  это строка подключения. Я для краткости убрал ее получение, но ее я считываю из вебконфига тут же в этом экшне